# Need help figuring C# regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to make a method that replaces simplified color tags from the given text with actual HTML tags, here is an example phrase:

INPUT: `<red>Hello<end> beautiful <#0000FF>world<end>`

OUTPUT: `<color=red>Hello</color> beautiful <color=#0000FF>world</color>`

So taking the the example the color tags, either with the color name or HEX code must be replaced with the HTML `<color=?>` tag and the `<end>` tags replaced with the `</color>` tag.

I know python, and for those of you who are familiar with it will understand this pattern: `\<(\w+)\>`
This is basically what I need in C#.

I am new to C# , so any help will be appreciated, thank in advance.

Comment: I would be surprised if it is different than in python. `\<(\w+?)\>` I think you just need the question mark to prevent greed.

Answer (score 0):

From a simple internet search I found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx

Where it states

```
(\w+?) Match one or more word characters, but as few characters 
as possible. Together, they form a group that can be referred to as \1
```

If for some reason `\<` does not work, try `[<]`. I would be surprised if it was much different than in python.